# Which Arch Linux file do I download?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

Which link do I need to click on to download Arch Linux?

On http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/iso/2015.08.01/ , there are two options: Dual and Bootstrap x64.

I have a 64bit PC, but I don't know if the dual one is 64bit compatible, and I have no idea what the bootstrap one is even for. I found an "explanation" on some website, but it didn't really explain it very well.

I don't *plan* to dual boot. I just want Arch as primary OS. But I may choose to dual boot in the future.

So, given that I have a 64bit PC, which link should I download? What's the difference between Dual and Bootstrap?

Comment: As far as i know the "dual" refers to both i686 and X86_64, not about a "dual boot".  Anyway, "archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso" is the current iso that many of us have happily installed to our purely linux machines.  Also consider the merits of downloading via torrent (magnet): https://www.archlinux.org/download/

Comment: Thank you @Theophrastus, currently downloading the torrent file.

Comment: @Theophrastus You should make that an answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should download the *archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso*, or better yet, the *archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso.torrent* file and download Arch Linux via a P2P application.

The *'dual'* [says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Download) that the ISO file is compatible for both x86_64 and i686 architecture computers.

The bootstrap image in the mirror is used for [installing Arch Linux on an existing Linux installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux#Method_A:_Using_the_bootstrap_image_.28recommended.29).

Choose the ISO that you need. It's also a good practice to download the *archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso.sig* file and verify that ISO file you have is the one you wanted.